# How can I preserve lists in a Pandas DataFrame when saving and loading from file?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column consisting of lists. E.g.

```
Idx  foo  bar  lists
0    ___  ___  [0, 1, 2]
1    ___  ___  [3, 4, 5]
```

I am unsure how to save this DataFrame to file and reload while preserving the list objects.

When using pd.to_csv, the list becomes a string representation. The eval() function would work, but the DataFrame has 10k+ rows and takes a long time.

When pickling and unpickling, I get the following error: UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ','. Which I believe is referring to the commas within each list.

How can I save and load this file without losing the lists?

Comment: pickling (with 'wb') and unpickling (with 'rb') works for me on your example - what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to `converters` keyword in the `pd.read_csv` function.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> df = pd.read_csv('some.csv',converters={'lists':literal_eval})
>>> df
Idx  foo  bar  lists
0    ___  ___  [0, 1, 2]
1    ___  ___  [3, 4, 5]
```